# ANDROID - ListView appear on button click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want create a ListView on a fragment.

That ListView must be "hide" and only appear when I clik a button.

> Attached pictures of what I need know.

[image: menu1]

[image: menu2]

[image: menu3]

1. If I click on center button (the arrow button) a ListView appear
   from bottom.
2. If I click again the arrow button a ListView hide again.

I dont need open new Activity, I need that ListView on the same Activity but I dont know how I can show ListView and Hide .

Can you help me for that?

Comment: Post some code whatever you tried...

Comment: do you need animated listview like sliding?

Comment: @RamkiAnba no, I dont need animated ListView

Comment: https://github.com/gunasiet/SlidingMenuExample in that menu button is on left hand side you just need to put in bottom

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MotionEvent`

Create a class by entending `SimpleOnGestureListener`.
You can find tutorial [here](http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118)

Answer (score 0):

Reference from this [Drawer Demo Project on GitHub](https://github.com/chemalarrea/DemoSlidingDrawer/tree/master/DemoSlidingDrawer)
You can use the class [MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer.java](https://github.com/chemalarrea/DemoSlidingDrawer/blob/master/DemoSlidingDrawer/src/it/sephiroth/demo/slider/widget/MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer.java) and include the `ListView` in a separate layout which will act as the container of what is going to slide up.

In your `Activity`, suppose the content view is: main_layout
i.e. `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);`

Then include the drawer in your `main_layout` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        arrow to open />

    <package.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/yourpackageforslider"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
                //here you specify the direction  
        my:direction="bottomToTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handle" //this is the button -arrow
        my:content="@+id/content" -content (which would identify your listview layout)>
        <include
            android:id="@id/content"
            layout="@layout/layoutContainingYourListview" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            button for it to push it up/down />
    </package.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your `listView` would remain completely independent of the code above and in a different layout -- layoutContainingYourListview. *This is good as the drawer sliding up becomes irrespective of its content - which you can change and work with dynamically too.*